# How to install vim into Minix3?

Tags: vim, minix

I should install `vim` into Minix. But I couldnt find any useful information on the net. I've just installed Minix on VirtualBox. So I am a beginner on Minix.

Do you have an idea how to install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this site, then navigate to your version and architecture:
ftp://ftp.minix3.org/pub/minix/packages/

For example, minix 3.3.0 on i386:
ftp://ftp.minix3.org/pub/minix/packages/3.3.0/i386/editors/vim-7.3.762.tgz

Comment: Here you find instructions on how to configure a package manager with this ftp: http://wiki.minix3.org/en/UsersGuide/InstallingBinaryPackages

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to compile from source? With a half-decent machine, compiling Vim doesn't take very long.

Though this tutorial on [how to compile Vim](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source) is geared towards Ubuntu, it's not to hard to adopt to other *nix systems.