# Installing VIM in Minix 3.1.8

Tags: minix

I've Googled this a thousand times and I cannot, for the life of me, get VIM to work on my Minix 3. For the record, I am running on a Windows machine with Minix 3 working on Oracle's VM VirtualBox.

I've tried typing,

```
# pkgin up && pkgin in vim
```

but I get the error:

```
pkgin: Can't open database /usr/var/db/pkgin/pkgin.db: unable to open database file: No such file or directory
```

I then try to do pkgin search git to search for a package, but I get the same error. Could this be some kind of Internet connection issue? I'm incredibly confused.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459372/minix-pkgin-error check if that answer suits your problem.

Comment: @Fernando I've been on that post and it didn't help me. That is why I had to create this one.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Try http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on the Minix 3 Google Groups Forums and they solved my problem. If anyone else has trouble, I'm pasting a response by Lionel:

Switch to http downloads by editing "/usr/pkg/etc/pkgin/repositories.conf" and comment out the line:
ftp://ftp.minix3.org/pub/minix/packages/$osrelease/$arch/All

and add the following:

http://www.minix3.org/pkgsrc/packages/$osrelease/$arch/All

Then do shutdown, boot, pkgin update and then install your desired packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, download the binary package from here:

ftp://ftp.minix3.org/pub/minix/packages/3.3.0/i386/editors/

Change "i386" to your correct architecture, if different.

As you're probably already familiar, this page tells you how to install binary packages for Minix:

http://wiki.minix3.org/en/UsersGuide/InstallingBinaryPackages

As far as your "pkgin" errors, here are two possible solutions:

http://osdir.com/ml/minix3/2011-03/msg00244.html

[How to install vim into Minix3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327085/how-to-install-vim-into-minix3)